# Return an array of mappings reflecting global state between struct associations?

Tags: solidity, arrays, mapping, struct

I am looking for a construct that's something like "return an list of key value pairs," which I think would be implemented as an array of mappings.  Is that right?

That is, I'd like a data structure that contains a list of (key,value) that I will use as a global state linking some structs to association with another.

What I mean is something like:

```
// so I have place structs
struct Place {
  uint8 placeid;
  string nameOfPlace;
  ...etc
}

// and a place can contain no more than 1 banner.    
// banners have all been to a place, but they aren't necessarily
// in a place right now. They may have been replaced with another 
// banner.
struct Banner {
  uint8 bannerid;
  uint8 placeAt; // this must match a placeid
  string thingTheBannerSays;
  uint8 timestamp;
}

Place[] places;                        // list all places
mapping(uint8 => Place)  placesById    // given an id, return the place
Banner[] banners;
mapping(uint8 => Banner)  bannersById  // given an id, return the place

// what's missing for me is a data structure
// with global state of [(place0,bannerN),(place1,bannerM)] 
// for all places.  This is what I'm looking for.

function listBannersAtPlacesRightNow() returns (???? arrayOfMappings) {
  ??? mappings[] = arrayOfMappings
  for(uint8 i =0; i < places.length; i++) {
     maxTime[i] = 0;       // declare this correctly
     idWhereMaxTime[i] = 0; // gross, would rather be null
     for(uint8 j=0; j < banners.length; j++) {
        if(banners[j].timestamp > maxTime[i]) {
          maxTime[i] = banners[j].timestamp // high water ;
          idWhereMaxTime[i] = banners[j];
        }
       }
     arrayOfMappings[i] = (places[i], idWheremaxTime[i]);
   }
 return arrayOfMappings;
 }
```

Sorry, I'm brand new to this, but if this unclear, in words, I'd like some variable to maintain the global state that says "I am a place, I can have 0 or 1 banners.  Here is a list of all the places and their current banners. Banners can be tied to exactly one place and never re-used."

Ugly quasi-python that might clarify ugly quasi solidity this would be something like:

```
places = [{"placeid": 0, "nameofplace": "home"}, {"placeid":1, "nameofplace": "center"}]

banners = [
{"bannerid": 0, "placeAt": 0, "thingthebannersays": "hello!"},
{"bannerid": 1, "placeAt": 0, "thingthebannersays": "hello again from home!"},
{"bannerid": 2, "placeAt": 0, "thingthebannersays": "this replaces 1!"},
{"bannerid": 3, "placeAt": 1, "thingthebannersays": "this is at center!"}]

bannerAtPlaces = [(0,2), #place 0 has current banner 2
                  (1,3)  #place 1 has banner 3
]

def setBannerAtPlaces(placeid, bannerid):
  # this updates bannerAtPlaces according to some rules
  # such as the most-recent timestamp given in the solidity
  # section

# BUT If I wanted to see which places contained which banners, I'd just
# print(bannerAtPlaces).  This is the call I'm looking to repeat
# in solidity.
```

This is all coming up because I'd rather have the struct for Place contain a field for bannerid, but unfortunately, I want Place to be able to have 0 banners, and it looks like I cannot initialize a null for that---I must default to `bannerid = 0`.  But `bannerid==0` is an actual bannerid.  It cannot be in two places at once, it's already somewhere else, and cannot be the default for the banner at all new places.

The reason for a list specifying global states would be for rendering this in the browser easily, as a gallery showing all (Place, Banner) pairs.

I am now seeing [a similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37606839/how-to-return-mapping-list-in-solidity-ethereum-contract).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't quite sure about the cardinality from your description. I went with "a banner can only be in one place at a time and a place either has or doesn't have exactly 1 banner."

The `for` loops are serious trouble in Solidity. We need to organize data structures so we can complete everything at a consistent gas cost at any scale - O(1). See this: https://blog.b9lab.com/getting-loopy-with-solidity-1d51794622ad

I don't think you need one-to-many joins, but in case you do have a look at this for ideas: https://medium.com/@robhitchens/enforcing-referential-integrity-in-ethereum-smart-contracts-a9ab1427ff42

That link sort of throws you in the deep end. It links to the CRUD series that explains the patterns I used to bang out this quick sketch:

```
pragma solidity 0.4.25;

contract Banners {

    struct BannerStruct {
        string marque;
        bytes32 placeId; // 0 or 1 placeId
        uint idPointer;
    }

    struct PlaceStruct {
        string name;
        bytes32 bannerId; // 0 or 1 bannerId
        uint idPointer;
    }

    mapping(bytes32 => BannerStruct) public bannerStructs;
    mapping(bytes32 => PlaceStruct) public placeStructs;

    bytes32[] public bannerIdList;
    bytes32[] public placeIdList;

    function getBannerCount() public view returns(uint) {
        return bannerIdList.length;
    }

    function getPlaceCount() public view returns(uint) {
        return placeIdList.length;
    }

    function isBanner(bytes32 bannerId) public view returns(bool) {
        if(bannerIdList.length==0) return false; // there aren't any, so false
        return bannerIdList[bannerStructs[bannerId].idPointer] == bannerId;
    }

    function isPlace(bytes32 placeId) public view returns(bool) {
        if(placeIdList.length==0) return false;
        return placeIdList[placeStructs[placeId].idPointer] == placeId;
    }

    function placeHasBanner(bytes32 placeId) public view returns(bool) {
        return isBanner(placeStructs[placeId].bannerId);
    }

    function newBanner(bytes32 bannerId, string marque) public returns(bool) {
        require(!isBanner(bannerId)); // no dups
        bannerStructs[bannerId].marque = marque;
        bannerStructs[bannerId].idPointer = bannerIdList.push(bannerId) - 1;
        return true;
    }

    function newPlace(bytes32 placeId, string name) public returns(bool) {
        require(!isPlace(placeId));
        placeStructs[placeId].name = name;
        placeStructs[placeId].idPointer = placeIdList.push(placeId) - 1;
        return true;
    }

    function setPlaceBanner(bytes32 placeId, bytes32 bannerId) public returns(bool) {
        require(isPlace(placeId));
        require(isBanner(bannerId));
        if(bannerStructs[bannerId].placeId != 0) { // moving it. A banner can only be in one place???
            bytes32 oldPlace = bannerStructs[bannerId].placeId;
            placeStructs[oldPlace].bannerId = bytes32(0);
        }
        bannerStructs[bannerId].placeId = placeId;
        placeStructs[placeId].bannerId = bannerId;
    }
}
```

As you press on, you'll also find that you probably want to reduce the amount of meta-data stored on-chain. I left my structs sparse for this reason. https://blog.b9lab.com/the-joy-of-minimalism-in-smart-contract-design-2303010c8b09

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is an very thorough answer and quite helpful as I start out.  Thank you.

Comment: Your links are also super helpful.  Regarding cardinality, I was shooting for  "a banner MUST only be in one place at a time and a place either has or doesn't have exactly 1 banner."  So the idea that a banner always has 1 place, but a place has 0 or 1 banners (say there is only 1 flagpole, but a large banner shed next to it).  I can work from your tips and links to there, though.  Thank you!

Comment: I wondered about that. The example is pretty close but it doesn't enforce the rule that every banner must have a place.  Certainly doable with a few more tweaks.